# Firebird multiple sums in select statement depending on boolean value in field of same row

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

This is exactly the same question as I did before only difference I am trying to run the same select on firebird sql.

I am trying to list Accounts with both their charges as well as payments on a single line and the only difference between charges and payments is the field Credit which is a Boolean either 1 or 0

```
 Select H.AccountNo,SUM(IF(G.Credit=0,SUM(F.Charge),NULL)) AS Debits,SUM(IF(G.Credit=1,SUM(F.Charge),NULL)) AS Credits
 from transdetails F
   left join transhead G on F.Transhead=G.Seqno
   left join Accounts H on H.SeqNo=G.Account
 Group by H.AccountNo
```

And this is what I would like the result to look like

```
H.Accounts  Debits     Credits
000221      131.00     NULL
000222      287.70     NULL
000223      70980.20   NULL
000224      13280.42   NULL
```

But this is the error message I am getting:

```
   ISC ERROR CODE:335544569

   ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
   Dynamic SQL Error
   SQL error code = -104
   Nested aggregate functions are not allowed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird doesn't support `IF` statement in DML, but you can use `CASE`. And you don't need to use "sum inside sum". Try something like this:

```sql
Select 
  H.AccountNo,
  SUM(CASE WHEN G.Credit = 0 THEN F.Charge END) AS Debits,
  SUM(CASE WHEN G.Credit = 1 THEN F.Charge END) AS Credits
from transdetails F
left join transhead G on F.Transhead=G.Seqno
left join Accounts H on H.SeqNo=G.Account
Group by H.AccountNo
```